# How can I run my Keras net on non-square images?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision

I trained a UNet based image segmentation model in `tf.keras` which predicts if and where an object is in a given image. I train with an input shape of `(None, 256, 256, 1)` and output a `(None, 256, 256, 3)` shaped prediction.

I now want to predict larger images (eg. `(520, 696)`) and want to use the same model. I am aware that one can change the input shape of the model to size `(None, None, None, 1)`. However, now it can still only predict square images – for the image mentioned above, it returns a `Dimensionality Error` as shapes don't match (520 != 696).

Does anyone know how to avoid this or have a working function to stitch together smaller square outputs?

Steps to error:

```
img = skimage.io.imread(X)  # shaped (520, 696)
pred = model.predict(img[None,...,None])
```

> InvalidArgumentError: _MklConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0][1]= 64 vs. shape[1][1] = 65
>        [[{{node concatenate_4/concat}}]]

Comment: It might be helpful if you include the _exact_ error you're getting.

Comment: Did you delete the old model (tensorflow will try to load the old model checkpoint with the old image dimensions)?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly – I rebuild the model (with different input size) and then only load the weights.

Comment: Sometimes I will run a model, it will save a checkpoint, then I restart the model but load different data and Tensorflow loads the saved model and then it explodes because the dimensions of the old model and the new data are different.  But if you aren't saving a checkpoint then nevermind.  I'd just note that 8 * 65 = 520.  and your error includes 65.  so something wrong is happening in that dimension but without any code and just an error message it is really hard to help you debug.  See if you can reproduce your problem with the least amount of code as possible and post that example.

Comment: I only save weights and reload them. I will try to find something small and reproducible. I would, however, expect that it might be easier to have some stitching of square-shaped predictions which might work. I'm just not sure how to do that efficiently

Comment: I just realised something – predictions don't actually work on all square images – only multiples of 256. I.e. 500x500 doesn't, but 512x512 works.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution – due to the fact, that I trained a UNet (with concatenation-layers after upsampling), it can only combine powers of 2 (eg. 256 / 512). I therefore have to add padding to bring it to the next power of two before prediction and remove padding from the output.